# Finding lead SNP's in GWAS - Find minimum value of rows grouped by proximity

Tags: r

I am trying to get the lead SNP's by region from the output of a GWAS analysis. What I needed to do is find the row with the lowest p-value of all SNP's nearby. Here is what my data looks like. (There are other columns but they don't matter for this selection).

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  SNP                chr       POS   Wald.pval
  <chr>            <int>     <int>       <dbl>
1 4:31970946:T:C       4  31970946 0.000000620
2 4:32001877:A:C       4  32001877 0.000000707
3 10:4627686:T:C      10   4627686 0.000000296
4 11:109015746:A:T    11 109015746 0.000000634
5 11:109018337:C:T    11 109018337 0.000000487
6 11:109018391:G:C    11 109018391 0.000000487
7 11:109019179:G:C    11 109019179 0.000000824
8 15:52448759:A:G     15  52448759 0.000000471
9 16:73596272:C:T     16  73596272 0.000000493\
```

And here is what I would like to have for the output. These are the lowest pval from each region where the position is within a certain distance. Here it is a position within 10,000. They also need to be on the same chromosome.

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  SNP                chr       POS   Wald.pval
  <chr>            <int>     <int>       <dbl>
1 4:31970946:T:C       4  31970946 0.000000620
2 10:4627686:T:C      10   4627686 0.000000296
3 11:109018337:C:T    11 109018337 0.000000487
4 15:52448759:A:G     15  52448759 0.000000471
5 16:73596272:C:T     16  73596272 0.000000493
```

I would prefer a tidyverse method for doing this and I would prefer not to have to use a loop on the whole data-structure but I would welcome any solution. Nearness isn't necessarily a set distance I would like to be able to evaluate how near each record is to it's neighbors and make a call based on that rather than a bulk cutoff but I can work with either.

Comment: Could you please add your source code, so that someone could check it. ans possinle erro messages too

Comment: @nbk I don't have any code. I am asking this question in order to get some idea of how to approach the problem. I don't even know what tools to use. If I had code I would have included it in my question. The data-structure listed comes from a completely unrelated analyses so I didn't include that code in order to avoid confusion. The results shown are from a manual select which I hope to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier if you use GenomicRanges packages. There you can separate them by chromosomes and also create so called regions. First we start with your tibble or dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(SNP = structure(c(8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L), .Label = c("10:4627686:T:C", "11:109015746:A:T", "11:109018337:C:T", 
"11:109018391:G:C", "11:109019179:G:C", "15:52448759:A:G", "16:73596272:C:T", 
"4:31970946:T:C", "4:32001877:A:C"), class = "factor"), chr = c(4L, 
4L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 15L, 16L), POS = c(31970946L, 32001877L, 
4627686L, 109015746L, 109018337L, 109018391L, 109019179L, 52448759L, 
73596272L), Wald.pval = c(6.2e-07, 7.07e-07, 2.96e-07, 6.34e-07, 
4.87e-07, 4.87e-07, 8.24e-07, 4.71e-07, 4.93e-07)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

We create GenomicRanges object

```
library(GenomicRanges)

# make a genomic range object
gr = GRanges(seqnames=df$chr,
IRanges(start=df$POS,end=df$POS),Wald.pval=df$Wald.pval)
names(gr) = df$SNP

# you can change this
FLANK = 10000
```

There is a nifty function in GenomicRanges call reduce, and I will explain how it works. First, we can extend the snp by using

```
flank(gr,FLANK,both=TRUE)

GRanges object with 9 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
                   seqnames              ranges strand | Wald.pval    region
                      <Rle>           <IRanges>  <Rle> | <numeric> <integer>
    10:4627686:T:C       10     4617686-4637685      * |  2.96e-07         3
   15:52448759:A:G       15   52438759-52458758      * |  4.71e-07         5
```

You can see this extends the snp both sides by 10kb. Now if we do reduce on this "flanked" region, it collapses them:

```
GRanges object with 6 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
      seqnames              ranges strand
         <Rle>           <IRanges>  <Rle>
  [1]        4   31960946-31980945      *
  [2]        4   31991877-32011876      *
  [3]       10     4617686-4637685      *
  [4]       11 109005746-109029178      *
  [5]       15   52438759-52458758      *
  [6]       16   73586272-73606271      *
```

For example, the region in chromosome 11 now encompass all your snps on chromosome 11. Next, it's a matter of reassigning your snps back to the regions and taking the smallest p-value

```
#flank your snps by 10kb and we merge all these regions together
REGIONS <- reduce(flank(gr,FLANK,both=TRUE))
# each SNP can only be matched to one merged region
# so we just find overlap between region and snp
# and assign the snp to the region
gr$region = subjectHits(findOverlaps(gr,REGIONS))
# order by pvalue
gr = gr[order(gr$Wald.pval),]
# keep only the top snp in each region
gr[!duplicated(gr$region)]

GRanges object with 6 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
                   seqnames    ranges strand | Wald.pval    region
                      <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <numeric> <integer>
    10:4627686:T:C       10   4627686      * |  2.96e-07         3
   15:52448759:A:G       15  52448759      * |  4.71e-07         5
  11:109018337:C:T       11 109018337      * |  4.87e-07         4
   16:73596272:C:T       16  73596272      * |  4.93e-07         6
    4:31970946:T:C        4  31970946      * |   6.2e-07         1
    4:32001877:A:C        4  32001877      * |  7.07e-07         2
```

Note, the last 2 snps on chr4, are keep because they are > 10kb apart.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll give it a shot and report back. I was hoping for something that didn't require installing a different package but if this works I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: This works well for me. I do want to make a quick note in case someone else runs into the problem that I did. In my environment, GenomicRanges::reduce ended up masked with a different reduce and I got this error: 'GRanges objects don't support [[, as.list(), lapply(), or unlist() at the moment.' Using the reduce from within the package fixed the problem but it took me a while to figure out what was wrong...